# Trouble creating lambda expression to achieve certain results

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, beautifulsoup

I have created a script in python using BeautifulSoup to parse some information from some html snippet. It is working fine when I use list comprehension. My goal here is to do the same using `lambda` expression. I've heard that the two `list comprehension` and `lambda expression` can work identically. However, I can't find any idea as to how I could apply `lambda` function to achieve the same result that I've got using `list comprehension`. Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Here is what my code so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

content="""
 <td align="right">0.00 %</td>,
 <td align="right">2.52</td>,
 <td align="right">1.79</td>,
 <td align="right">1.79 % </td>,
 <td align="right">0.72</td>,
 <td align="right">1.08 %</td>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"lxml")
data = [item.text for item in soup.find_all("td")] #it is doing fine
# data = "wish to do the same like above using lambda"
print(data)
```

Comment: Lambdas are not considered pythonic. List comprehension is readable.

Comment: @Rahul, I do not claim to have said something like that in my post.

Comment: I also don't claim anything. Just saying. You can do whatever you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most I can think of is applying a `lambda` using `map`:

```
map(lambda x: x.text,soup.find_all("td"))
```

This is a generator expression in Python 3, so either iterate it or `list()` around it. As mentioned in the commons, a `map` is more of an afterthought of the creator of Python, you can explicitly write out a generator expression by substituting the `[]` for `()` in your comprehension.

Comment: Did you mean `x.next` or `x.text`?

Comment: @shayan Thanks, fixed.

Comment: Amazing solution!! Plus one for this. Gonna accept it when system allows me to do so. Thanks.

Comment: @shayan Thanks, but also consider reading the answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map for some good knowledge on Python (and comments therein).